# Securing Glassfish REST Service with basic auth using annotations

Tags: rest, annotations, glassfish, glassfish-3, basic-authentication

I have been trying to secure an application, which is deployed to glassfish 3 using annotation instead of the deployment descriptor. However, I haven't been able to get it working correctly. If I try to access the service, I end up with a server error 500, which displays this message:

```
type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
root cause

javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
```

The EJB looks like this:

```
@Path("/myresource")
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("user-role")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{uuid}")
    public Response getData(@PathParam("uuid") final String uuid) {
            ....
    }
}
```

sun-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" 
"http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>user-role</role-name>
        <group-name>user-group</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
</sun-web-app>
```

This is the web.xml:

```
<web-app id="myservice" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>org.test.myservice</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.test.myservice.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user-role</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

The file realm in glassfish is set up using the user and role specified in the sun-web.xml and has been working well, when setting up the application security via deployment descriptor.

If I understand this document correctly I do not have to link security role references if their names are the same. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html#bnbyt
Any ideas what I am missing?

**Edit**
Related to the problem of not being able to specify the required information with annotations, there is a another problem, which caused me to think about this issue. Maybe that will make the initial question a little clearer:
Taken above example, the resource /myresource/* is only available for users with role 'user-role'. However, if there is a second resource at path /myresource/*/thumbnail (translating to /myresource/[uuid]/thumbnail) which should be available without authentication, this is not possible by specifying security-constraints with url-mapping, since it does not seem to be possible to use the wildcard between constants. However, this would be doable by specifying the roles, that are allowed to access a method by annotions. As described above, I haven't been able to do so. How could a mapping like that be done?

Comment: How are you accessing the restful web service MyResource? Directly from the client? Or internally on the server side? (How) have you authenticated the client?

Comment: I am accessing it using a browser, as it is just a get request. However, we also have tests, which use apache http client to access the resources. The client should authenticate via basic auth. So, the browser, should display a pop-up automatically. The apache http client is configured to send the credentials. I just did some more tests. As soon as I remove the security constraint section from our old web.xml, I end up with the http 500 error. That just doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Haven't you added the security-constraint element in web.xml?

Comment: Well, the plan was to replace the security-constraint with the corresponding annotations on the classes and methods. If I understand the documentation correctly, you are either able to use the deployment descriptor OR annotations for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [security-constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017885) element in web.xml descriptor in order to block specific resources and paths, and to specify the authorization constraints.

This doesn't mean that you can't add more fine-grained controls using Programmatic Security, as explained in [Oracle's Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxe.html):

> Programmatic security is embedded in an application and is used to make security decisions. Programmatic security is useful when declarative security alone is not sufficient to express the security model of an application.

---

As per your **edited** question.

I would use the `security-constraint` element for blocking the access to all non-registered users. This will force everybody to authenticate, so that your application knows the roles they have.
Then you can fine-grain control the access to the various resources using programmatic security.

With basic authentication I guess there are no other ways. If you want to avoid authentication for basic users, you need to go with form authentication and handle the authentication programmatically behind the scenes, authenticating them even if they aren't aware of, by using [HttpServletRequest#login()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

In both ways you should be able to setup rights in the way you have described. If you want to handle the unauthorized exception more smoothly, you'd better remove the `@RolesAllowed` annotation and instead use something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/{uuid}")
public Response getData(@PathParam("uuid") final String uuid, @Context SecurityContext sc) {
    if (sc.isUserInRole("MyRole")) {
        return result;
    } else {
        return notAllowedResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't fully understand. If I would add a security constraint like that <security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Secure</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/myresource/*</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>user-role</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint> What is the purpose of the annotation? The annotation on a method essentially provides the same information as the security constraint (e.g. a path (url), a role and a method).

Comment: No. @Path annotation is the Jersey-REST resource path. It has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Well, if I understand this correctly now, basic auth is provided by the jersey servlet, which is configured by the security-constraint. As the jersey url-mapping does not support mappings that depend on the value after the wildcard, I can not disable basic auth for the */thumbnail resource. So, in the end I can not configure jersey to do what I want using basic auth. If I want to rely on the annotations only, I will not get the basic auth handling one would usually expect, but security on the EJB level. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The Roles-Allowed is an EJB construct and not congruent with access to the resource, which is handled by the security constraint.

Unfortunately, the two security concepts do not mesh as well as they should, and instead of getting a 401 if you're not authorized (a web concept), you get the security exception that you are receiving (and EJB concept). In fact, I don't know what error you will receive if you annotate an EJB web service with a RolesAllowed and try to access the web service with an invalid role. I assume you'll get a SOAP fault, in that case.

The EJB security is a system that keeps unauthorized people out, but it's a last ditch effort. It assumes that any decisions to route folks to the method calls is already done up front. For example, there's no high level way to test if a method is allowed or not, rather you can only call it and catch the exception.

So the harsh truth is beyond coarse gatekeepers, you want to leverage Programmatic Security.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have understood that and why I can not use the @RolesAllowed annotation to secure my resources. Nevertheless I am still looking for a way to have a basic auth secured resource /myresource/* and a subsequent open resource /myresource/*/thumbnail. Is there any way I can achieve that without jumping through hoops?

Comment: Did You manage to solve that problem? I've got the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947415/basic-authentication-in-rest-application